# openswan l2tp server to android client

Tags: android, linux, vpn

I'm trying to figure out how to set up openvpn on my linux mint so I can connect to it with my android (T-Mobile HTC MyTouch 4G Slide) device.  I think I'm part way there but I am still having fits getting it to connect.

So far I have installed openswan, openssl and tinyca
I was able to create a CA certificate and a request certificate in tinyca. If I am reading it correct it creates them using the openssl settings so I copied the /etc/ssl/cert/MyserverCert.pem and /etc/ssl/private/MyserverKey.pem to the appropriate directories in /etc/ipsec.d/*
I copied the example l2tp-psk.conf into /etc/ipsec.d/ and modified the left to my eth0 interface address, and leftnexthop to my router address, saved then restarted ipsec service.
I generated a Myserver.crt file using tinyca from the existing ssl keys and sent it to my phone and was able to import it.

Where I'm confused is when I try to set up an L2TP PSK vpn in my phone, it is asking for 'username'. It also has a setting when you set up the connection that asks for 'IPSec pre-shared key' - I'm assuming this is the name I gave the .crt settings when I imported them?

Any other tips/suggestions would be greatly appreciated (like where to look in log files to see what might be failing and why both on the phone and on the server)

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: I prefer you get the ipsec work first. l2tp is based on ipsec.

Comment: @arsane, on Android you could not do a "pure IPsec" VPN until very recently (Android 4.0), so it's not possible to test IPsec without L2TP. Moreover, L2TP is not "based on" IPsec at all. However, I think what you meant is that the L2TP protocol is not secure, and is intended to be secured by IPsec. Now, on Android, you can set up an L2TP VPN *without* IPsec, and this might be a good first test. But I wouldn't want to use it in production without IPsec's protection.

Comment: @Mike, correct, l2tp need not based on ipsec though it does. I mean a third pc can be used to verify that the server's ipsec/l2tp is okay first.

Answer (score 2):

[This guide](http://blog.riobard.com/2010/04/30/l2tp-over-ipsec-ubuntu) worked for me.

To see what's happening on the phone, I always use `adb logcat`. (There may be an app to view this log, but I just use the `adb` tool in the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk).)

Note however that if you are using certificates, you won't use a pre-shared key. When you go to create the VPN connection on your Android device, you'll need to select `L2TP/IPsec CRT VPN` instead of `L2TP/IPsec PSK VPN`.

If you were using a "pure" IPsec VPN, you would not necessarily need a "username". The "username/password" aspect, in this case, is added by the L2TP component of the VPN. (there are other types of IPsec VPNs which use username/password authentication in addition to a PSK or certificate; this type of authentication is usually called "XAUTH".)